# In graph, access node connections by edge name

Tags: python, graph, networkx, knowledge-graph

I have a knowledge base graph (built in `networkx`).

Here is made up example.

```
G = nx.DiGraph()
G.add_edge('user1', 'New York', relation = 'works at')
G.add_edge('user1', 'Boston', relation = 'from')
G.add_edge('user1', '27', relation = 'Age')
```

[image: graph relations]

Between each pair of nodes I have specific relation such as 'works at', 'from', etc

I want to check if I have desired edge for specific node. For example, do I know information about where **user1 works at**.

Currently, I do it in a loop:

```
for connected_node, attributes in G['user1'].items():
    if attributes['relation'] == 'works at':
        print(True, connected_node)
```

Is it possible to check if a node has specific edge without loop?

And consequently get connected node by this edge?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, you'll have to iterate over the edges of the node to see if any of them matches the search criteria. The only *minor* improvement I can think of, is to search only among the out-edges of the node with [`DiGraph.out_edges`](https://networkx.github.io/documentation/stable/reference/classes/generated/networkx.DiGraph.out_edges.html):

```
for source, dest, d in G.out_edges('user1', data=True):
    if d.get('relation') == 'works at':
        print(f'Connected node {source} -> {dest}')
# Connected node user1 -> New York
```

Comment: So, is it correct that I cannot uniquely index edges for each node? Like having dictionary inside dictionary? 
If no, maybe there are other frameworks with such capabilities?

Comment: I'm mostly have experience with nx when it comes to graph analysis, so not so sure about the second point @VadymB. And no, you have to traverse the list of edges of a given node in search for the one that has the attribute of interest. You'd have to *know* which edge has the parameter in question for that. Btw don't forget you can upvote answers too :)